# Как ввести строку посредством scanf?

Tags: c++

допустим есть структура

```
struct A
{
    char str[100];
}
```

Как при помощи scanf ввести эту строку из консоли?

Если делать так:

```
scanf_s("%99s", a.str);
```

то выдает исключение на запись.

Comment: Если вводить при помощи cin, то все корректно работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно передавать размер буфера:

```
scanf_s("%s", a.str, 100);
```